# Facebook Cover Image Reposition Code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'd like to know how is it possible to develop a "drag and reposition cover" application like Facebook?
I already know I gotta use AJAX, so the image will be uploaded without refreshing its page. Now I gotta figure out what kind of JavaScript code will do the job for image repositioning.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: FYI: Just that you want to implement something in a way coincidentally Facebook does as well, does not justify tagging with `facebook` or `facebook-javascript-sdk` – those tags are for questions specific to developing _for_ the FB platform or using their SDK. (Tags removed.)

Comment: This is an awfully broad "question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have image, you can try using [JQ Image Drag](http://puneetk.com/jq-image-drag/) plugin to do repositioning like facebook.

You need to specify few parameters like the sample code below

```
$('.wrap').imagedrag({
          input: "#output",
          position: "middle",
          attribute: "html"
        });
```